# Deleting infomation from a binary file

Tags: c, file, binary, editing

Hello my problem is the following;

i have this struct

```
struct item{
    char id[5];
    int ing[10];
    float qtd[10];
};
```

and i have a binary file with information, and i want to delete a selected id, i tryed this

```
int remove(){   
    FILE *origem;
    FILE *copia;
    char menu[10];
    struct item aux;
    origem=fopen("menu.bin","rb");
    copia=fopen("temp.bin","wb");
    if(origem==NULL || copia==NULL)
        return;

    do{

        printf("name to delete");
        scanf("%s",&menu);

        if(stricmp(menu,aux.id)!=0)
            fwrite(&aux,sizeof(aux),1,copia);

    }while(fread(&aux,sizeof(aux),1,origem)==1);

    fclose(origem);
    fclose(copia);
    remove("menu.bin");
    rename("temp.bin","menu.bin");

}
```

can you help me? 
i want to copy the cotents except the ID i choose.
thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Did it work? What happened?

Comment: first of all, scans is not going to work in a binary this type of binary operation.  YOu are going to need to used the fread routine with a sizeof(item) as the size of the item you are trying to read.  You will read in one "item" at a time, the perform a strcmp of the id and inside the struct and the string id you wish to skip.  If they are equal, skip, if not, then write to file.

Comment: That code snippet will not even compile in a C compiler, as you have named your function `rename` and also calling a system function `rename`.

Comment: @trumpetlicks The poster is using `scanf` to get a name from the user, i.e. from `stdin` not from a file.

Comment: the function name is remove , not rename!

Comment: @Greg Hewgill , i tried other things but only ended up with and exact copy of the previous file...

Comment: So after editing your post to format the code a bit better, you are asking for a name to delete for each time through your loop.  You are also going to at that point only perform a comparison of the current menu to the current singular "item" currently read from the binary file.  Try moving your printf / scanf code just above the do{ and entering an ID that you KNOW is in the file.  See what happens then.  I have pasted your code within an answer with the edit I am speaking of.

Comment: Did any of the provided answers, answer your question / need?

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing the below to at least see what happens.  In this case your program will only take in 1 ID to attempt deleting from the binary file, instead of getting a new ID to compare for each struct read in from the binary.

```
int remove(){   
    FILE *origem;
    FILE *copia;
    char menu[10];
    struct item aux;
    origem=fopen("menu.bin","rb");
    copia=fopen("temp.bin","wb");
    if(origem==NULL || copia==NULL)
        return;

    printf("name to delete");
    scanf("%s",&menu);

    // to read first record into struct aux
    fread(&aux,sizeof(aux),1,origem);

    do{

        if(stricmp(menu,aux.id)!=0)
            fwrite(&aux,sizeof(aux),1,copia);

    }while(fread(&aux,sizeof(aux),1,origem)==1);

    fclose(origem);
    fclose(copia);
    remove("menu.bin");
    rename("temp.bin","menu.bin");
}
```

Comment: This is essential what is in my answer but using a while loop rather than a do-while loop with an initializer.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `printf`/`scanf` stuff outside the loop, use `while(fread(...)) { ... }` instead of `do { ... } while(fread(...))` (kind of pointless to check id and maybe write before you've read something from the file).